# change state in Typescript with props

Tags: typescript, state, react-props

I am new to React/Typescript and I am trying to create a loading page before rendering some orders
I have the following main class OrderUi:

```
const OrderUi = () => {
   const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false as boolean);
   return (
      <table>
       {loading ?
         orders.map((order: Order, key: number) => (
         <OrderOverview key={key} order={order} setLoading={setLoading}/>
         )) : <LoadingPage />}
      </table>
   );
export {OrderUi};
```

This is my OrderOverview

```
interface OrderOverviewProps {
setLoading: (loading: boolean) => void;
}

export const OrderOverview = (props: { order: Order } & OrderOverviewProps) => {
    props.setLoading(true);
    return (
      <tr key={props.order.orderNumber}>
            <td>
                <span>{props.order.timestamp.toString().substring(0, 10)}<br/>
                    {props.order.timestamp.toString().substring(11, 16)}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <p><span>{props.order.orderNumber}</span></p>
                    <a className="detailsLink keyNav-element">Details</a>
                </div>
            </td>
     </tr>
   );};
```

And this is LoadingPage

```
const LoadingPage = () =>
(
    <div>
        <p>Loading</p>
    </div>
);

export {LoadingPage};
```

I don't know if my logic is correct, I still receive the loading=false and I hope you could give me some advices of what can I do

Comment: `setLoading` will never be called because `OrderOverview` will never render

Comment: any idea how to change that?

Comment: What are `orders`?

Comment: I forgot to add in OrderUi before const [loading, set... the orders:
    const [orders, setOrders] = React.useState([] as Order[]);
*Order is an interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `useEffect` hook for that:

```
const OrderUi = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true as boolean);
    const [orders, setOrders] = React.useState([] as Order[]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (orders.lenght > 0) {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }, [orders]);
    return (
        <table>
            {!loading ?
                orders.map((order: Order, key: number) => (
                    <OrderOverview key={key} order={order} />
                )) : <LoadingPage />}
        </table>
    );
}
export { OrderUi };
```